# Graph many series which are all in one column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, bash, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to find a quick way to take Cloudwatch metrics and graph them in excel because it's too much data for Cloudwatch to render in one API call. I only need one metric, but I need it from 526 EC2 instances and I need it for several months.

So far I've fetched all the data

```
mkdir /tmp/i
jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[]|select([.Tags[].Value == "'"$tag"'"]|any).InstanceId' /tmp/instances \
  | xargs -n1 -P6 sh -c 'aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics  \
--namespace the_namespace --metric-name the_metric_name \
--dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=$0 \
--statistics Average \
--start-time $start  \
--end-time $end \
--period 86400 \
--region us-west-2  | tee /tmp/i/$0'
```

And can dump the data in CSV format:

```
(cd /tmp/i; find . -type f -print0 | xargs --null -n1 sh -c "jq -c '.Datapoints[]|[\"'\$0'\",.Timestamp,.Average]|@csv' /tmp/i/\$0" | sort)
```

Now there are two challenges:

1. The data is sparse. If an instance was stopped during a period there won't be a zero datapoint, there will be no datapoints. I think Excel can handle this if I set the X axis values for the timeseries
2. The series are all in one big column. For example:

```
....
"./i-oneoneoneoneoneone","2021-02-04T00:00:00Z",0
"./i-oneoneoneoneoneone","2021-02-05T00:00:00Z",0.0002314814814814815
"./i-oneoneoneoneoneone","2021-02-06T00:00:00Z",0
"./i-oneoneoneoneoneone","2021-02-07T00:00:00Z",0
"./i-oneoneoneoneoneone","2021-02-08T00:00:00Z",0
"./i-oneoneoneoneoneone","2021-02-09T00:00:00Z",0
"./i-oneoneoneoneoneone","2021-02-10T00:00:00Z",0
"./i-twotwotwotwotwotwo","2020-11-15T00:00:00Z",0
"./i-twotwotwotwotwotwo","2020-11-16T00:00:00Z",0
"./i-twotwotwotwotwotwo","2020-11-17T00:00:00Z",0
"./i-twotwotwotwotwotwo","2020-11-18T00:00:00Z",0
"./i-twotwotwotwotwotwo","2020-11-19T00:00:00Z",0
"./i-twotwotwotwotwotwo","2020-11-20T00:00:00Z",0
...
```

I imagine Excel wants them more like:

```
"","i-oneoneoneoneoneone","","i-twotwotwotwotwotwo", ...
"2021-02-04T00:00:00Z",0,"2020-11-15T00:00:00Z",0
"2021-02-05T00:00:00Z",0.0002314814814814815,"2020-11-16T00:00:00Z",0
"2021-02-06T00:00:00Z",0,"2020-11-16T00:00:00Z",0
"2021-02-07T00:00:00Z",0,"2020-11-17T00:00:00Z",0
"2021-02-08T00:00:00Z",0,"2020-11-18T00:00:00Z",0
"2021-02-09T00:00:00Z",0,"2020-11-19T00:00:00Z",0
"2021-02-10T00:00:00Z",0,"2020-11-20T00:00:00Z",0
...
```

Where series are in adjacent pairs of (x,y) columns. Seeing as I have hundreds of these, I would really hate to have to cut & paste them.

Comment: Since you are using Excel then first you have to convert CSV data to Columns,, better [edit] you post & share your WB ,, in which you have source data & the Graph you have plotted,,help us to fix it!

Comment: I'm not really tied to excel. I started looking at GNU plot but it doesn't seem like it can do stacked area graphs, which is my desired graph type without some trickery. For it to work, I'd need non-sparse data: https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/creating-a-filled-stack-graph-in-gnuplot/

Comment: ,, in that case case better post this issue at appropriate FORUM !!